# Compare LDAP date to epoch

Tags: java, date, ldap, datetime-comparison

I'm trying to calculate LDAP accountExpires.
The given value is LDAP date - nanoseconds since `01/01/1601 00:00`.

What is the best way to test if it is indeed after `new Date()`?

Comment: What did your search and research bring up? What have you tried?

Comment: Accorinding to [this page](https://www.epochconverter.com/ldap) the LDAP time is really in 100-nanoseconds intervals. Do you know whether this is correct for the number you have got? Could you give an example input and desired output?

Comment: @OleV.V. - a very unfriendly way... convert the attribute value to milliseconds, then create a `Date` with Jan-01-1601, then add the ms to that date, and then check if `after()` now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way probably depends on your precision requirements. I suggest

```
private static final Instant ldapEpoch = LocalDateTime.of(1601, Month.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0)
                                .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                                .toInstant();
```

and then

```
long ldapTime = 131_428_662_140_000_000L;
Instant convertedTime = ldapEpoch.plusMillis( ldapTime / 10_000L );
System.out.println(convertedTime.isAfter(Instant.now()));
```

With my example LDAP time value this produces an `Instant` of `2017-06-25T12:10:14Z` and prints `false` because the time is not after the current time.

Since you mentioned `new Date()` in the question, I assumed that the precision of `Date` would suffice for you, that is, milliseconds. I would really have loved to do `ldapEpoch.plusNanos(ldapTime * 100)` to keep the full precision, but this overflows the Java `long` data type and therefore gives an incorrect result. If you need the full precision, … **Edit:** as suggested by Basil Bourque in a comment, slice off the fractional second, work in whole seconds, then add back your fractional second:

```
    Instant convertedTime = ldapEpoch.plusSeconds( ldapTime / 10_000_000L )
                                    .plusNanos( ldapTime % 10_000_000L * 100L );
```

(The way I had first presented works too, gives the same result; but the edited version may be more natural to readers who know the Java date & time API (and may also perform a slight bit better, but that’s hardly critical).)

Why I wanted to multiply by 100? The [LDAP, Active Directory & Filetime Timestamp Converter I found](https://www.epochconverter.com/ldap) says “The timestamp is the number of 100-nanoseconds intervals (1 nanosecond = one billionth of a second) since Jan 1, 1601 UTC.”

Beware that in 1601 not everyone agreed about calendars, so January 1 that year is ambiguous. Most computer software assumes the Gregorian calendar, so I guess the definition of LDAP time does too, it’s not something I know.

Comment: To keep the full precision, slice off the fractional second, then work in whole seconds. To that result, add back your fractional second. This is how java.time classes work internally : whole seconds *plus* a fraction of a second as nanoseconds.